# I'm doing the same if statement in various places. How could i make this more efficient?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, if-statement

In my app, it finds out the week day in various places and performs various tasks. For example:

```
if ([weekDayString isEqualToString:@"Monday"]) {

mondayAlarm = @"ON";

}

else if ([weekDayString isEqualToString:@"Tuesday"]) {

tuesdayAlarm = @"ON";

}
```

etc.

And in various places in my code it does the same set of 7 if statements with different outputs. So i have 2 questions about making it less repetitive.

1. Is there a way that i could get this down to just the 7 if statements, without repeating each one for each area i want something to happen?
2. You'll notice my variables relating to the weekday all have the weekday in them. Is there any way that i could do this in a smarter way than repeat more or less the same code 7 times?

Help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: are **mondayAlarm, tuesdayAlarm,** etc instance variables?

Comment: Can't you use an array to represent the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from Yakuru and the request for more detail:

```
typedef enum Days { SUN, MON, TUE, WED, THUR, FRI, SAT, NUMBER_OF_DAYS } Days;

@interface MyClassWithAlarms
{
   Bool alarms[NUMBER_OF_DAYS];
}

- (void) setAlarmOnDay:(Days)day;

@end

@implementation MyClassWithAlarms

- (void) setAlarmOnDay:(Days)day
{
   alarms[day] = YES;
}

@end
```

etc.

You can freely mix C and Objective-C. For an array of just 7 booleans there is no point in using an NSArray, a C array will be much faster and use less memory. You won't get bounds checking though, so make sure your index is always in range - which it will be if you only use `Days` values.

Comment: Thanks for your help here. I understand this mostly, and how to implement it, but what i'm wondering is a few things now. 1.What purpose does NUMBER_OF_DAYS serve, and why's it referred to? 2. Why is Days mentioned before and after? 3. Why does it start with typedef before enum?

Comment: (a) In C enum literals are given values starting at 0 and incrementing by 1 each time, so SUN is just a name for 0, SAT for 6. By adding NUMBER_OF_DAYS at the last literal its value is the number of preceding literals - 7 in this case - which is the size the array needs to be. (b) the typedef allows the "enum Days" to be referred to as just "Days" - you can write it as "typedef enum { ... } Days" if you like.

Comment: Apart from the typos, yes - as defined in the sample code the call is `[self setAlarmOnDay:MON]`. Note you can use any valid identifier for the enum, I'd probably use `typedef enum { Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, NUMBER_OF_DAYS} Days` myself - and then you can use `Monday` as you did.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an enumeration rather than a string for the current day, then instead of having a bunch of weekday variables you could have an array of size NUM_WEEKDAYS
Then your code would be more like:

`Alarms[weekDay] = ON;`

Some more details since this is fairly C-like:
First an enumeration associates integers with values. So here's a sample enumeration:

```
enum Days
{
    MON,
    TUES,
    WEDS,
    THURS,
    FRI,
    SAT,
    SUN,
    NUM_WEEKDAYS
};
```

So an array holds each value in sequence, so rather than having:

```
MonAlarm
TuesAlarm
WedsAlarm
...
```

You would just have `Alarms[NUM_WEEKDAYS]`. Then you could access Monday's alarm via `Alarms[MON]` The same way you used to refer to `mondayAlarm`.

The other issue is that you are accessing your days of the week via string, this should be avoided -- string operations are SLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOW. Use the enumeration instead, if possible. Where are you pulling this string from? Give me some details and I'll show you how to clean that up. Once you get to the point your input is the enumeration value "MON" you pass it straight through without any need for an if.

Comment: Thanks, that's so much more consise. But i don't understand 'you could have an array of size NUM_WEEKDAYS'. Could you explain this for me? And also, how could i set the number inside the bracket to a new number? For example, changing it to the number 6?

Comment: My code is straight C, not very objective-C like. Apologies for that. The way it would work is this: `enum Weekdays { MON, TUES, WEDS, THURS, FRI, SAT, SUN, NUM_WEEKDAYS }; bool Alarms[NUM_WEEKDAYS];` would construct a C-style array with each day. Is that clear?

Comment: Not really, sorry. Could somebody who knows C and Objective-C sort of translate how this would work?

Comment: I understand this now. Thank you for your help here!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that, rather than dealing with the string in your initial data structure, you use an integer or enum value.  It's more efficient to deal with integers (or enums) than strings.  Only translate the integer value into a string when you need to display it.

Any day-of-week-specific processing can be done in a switch statement as opposed to a chain of if-else statements doing string comparisons.

This approach also makes localization easier, in the event you decide to use your app in a non-English-speaking country.

I'd recommend using the same day-of-week convention used by NSDateComponents.

Answer (score 0):

Us a NSDictionary to hold the Alarm values accessing the values with the days as the key. See [Apple collections documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Dictionaries.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000134-CJBCBGII) This is not exact code as yo do not give enough context but ..

```
// create
NSMutableDictionary* alarms = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
// set up the days
[alarms setObject:@"ON" forKey:@"Monday"];   // etc.
```

After all dates set then just can get the value with

```
[alarms valueForKey:@"Monday"];
```